# how to login directly into facebook using facebook api through my ASp.net webservice using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

i created a mathod facebookInfo(string username,string password) ,so i received username and password but after receiving its not possible to login at server side,because ther is only one way to connect to facebook using facebook api ie.

facebookservie.ConnectToFacebook();

and its open IE browser,so there is any way to login automatically and get session,using any javascript or nay other way at server side using ASp.net in C#...pls help me..my whole project depend on this.....thanks in advance

Comment: You want people to enter their username and password on your site...?

Comment: my project is based on whatsapp or like a fring messenger so i need user of my application enter their facebook details and instead of client side login ,i want user login through my web service,which is on server side.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remotely login a user from your site using their login details. This is against the Facebook terms and conditions. If you want to make requests via the graph api then you have to options:

1. You could acquire an access_token from Facebook and make requests as an application
2. You could allowed the user to login and request the offline_access permission, which allows you to make requests on behalf of the user without requiring them to have an active session

What exactly do you want to do to interact with Facebook? What you are currently doing sounds an awful lot like phishing...

Comment: Agreed. YOu are not allowed to do this. You have to request an access token. Check out this SDK for samples on how to do that: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: no its not a phishing it is part of my project,but client need facebook login through server side not on client side,because our project running on six mobile platform brew,android,windows mobile,iphone,blackbery and symbian so ,its too difficult to do facebook login using facebook api for this different platform ,thats why we need method should be developed on server side ,so everyone only have to call web service and pass username and password to server and then in server side using facebook api in c# method implemented,so its legal or illegal

Comment: Well i'm afraid you cannot do that. You will have to implement the various authentication methods on the platforms